# What is a reasonable definition for "is"? What is the rule for inserting it in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, third-person

I am learning a foreign language with the help of an excellent tutor who speaks enough English for me to be able to understand them. The deal is, essentially, I correct their English if they teach/correct Malaysian.

Today I got a bit stuck. They provided the following statement:

> That not exactly correct

This is clearly understandable. The obvious response is:

> That **is** not exactly correct

I'm struggling to explain *why* one is preferable to the other. Bearing in mind they have little-to-no understanding of esoteric grammar rules (same here, to be honest).

Google tells me it is the "third person singular of 'be'". Fantastic. What, exactly, does that mean? Also, how can I explain this using relatively simple English to a non-native speaker?

Any responses are very much appreciated, by myself as much as the ultimate recipient.

(And hell, if you want to pick holes in the grammar/vocabulary of this post, please do)

Aside: I have checked for questions related to this, but I'm sure you can appreciate that "is" is (oh the irony) a bloody difficult search query. A search query for "[is]" (questions tagged with "is") returns nothing, so again, please help :)

Comment: English sentences require a verb.  The first phrase does not have one.

Comment: I would strongly urge you to consider using [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) - you'll probably get better answers more targeted to non-native speakers. In your case, *that* is a noun (the thing you're talking about), and *not exactly correct* is an adjectival phrase (which describes an attribute of *that*). The verb "to be" is used to link the noun to the adjective, and it's "third person singular" because grammatically that's how we refer to *one of anything that isn't either "me" or "you"*.

Comment: Sentences need a verb to be correct. "That not exactly correct" does not contain a verb. The word "is" is a verb that equates something (that) to another thing (not exactly correct).

Comment: Does a sentence require a verb? No.

Comment: The speed of your responses is simply astonishing.

So: @FumbleFingers thank you, your response is the most enlightening. Would I be correct in stating that "is" has no grammatical value aside from being a copula?

Comment: @MattЭллен Could you provide an example? This has no bearing on the question, but I'm simply curious.

Comment: @ craig0990: Probably - your example would strike native speakers as typical for a *non-native speaker*, precisely because ***is*** there has no real significance ("meaning") apart from the fact that English syntax requires it in your exact construction. But native speakers almost *always* include it unless deliberately poking fun at non-native speech patterns (as in *"Me Tarzan, you Jane"*, where the implication is Tarzan doesn't know how to speak properly because he's "uneducated").

Comment: @FumbleFingers Excellent, I don't look like quite such an uneducated fool. Does there exist a sentence where "is" changes the meaning of a sentence? Would you care to make an answer out of that so I can accept it, or is there some other etiquette I'm unaware of on this StackExchange?

Comment: @ craig0990: I would prefer not to answer questions like this on ELU (I do on ELL as per my previous link, but actually there are others who can do better than me in many cases). Matt's answer here is perfectly correct, though I sense it's not exactly the level of response you were hoping for.

Comment: In future I will use ELL, thank you very much for pointing that resource out. This was simply the first thought that came into my mind for this kind of question (which you've probably all noticed is my first, and I'm glad it wasn't dismissed as duplicate/irrelevant). I think @RegDwiht has it nailed, so I'll take that as the answer and try to re-formulate it for my friend tomorrow (it's 3am here, and I have work later).

Not to say Matt wasn't correct, but RegDwiht details precisely why/why not to do this in English.

Comment: *Yes.* *No.* *Thank you.* Although some people will argue that *thank* is a verb.

Comment: @MattЭллен aren't those examples phrases and not sentences precisely because they lack verbs?

Comment: The verb "to be" is a very unusual verb. Most English verbs have four or five forms: jump, jumps, jumped, jumping. Drive, drives, drove, driven, driving. The verb "to be" is I believe the only one with nine: be, is, am, are, was, were, will, been, being. (And we've lost art, wast and wert, which are found in Shakespeare but not modern English.) It is *highly irregular* and it is difficult to describe to the non-English speaker precisely what all the rules are.

Comment: What am I thinking, "will" isn't a form of "to be". Eight. Eight forms. And Shakespearean English also had "beest". What a crazy verb.

Comment: Irrelevant side comment: "It is said that the ultimate question of most literature is 'who am I'. Science fiction takes that one step further and questions the meanings of those three words."

Comment: @terdon: that's circular reasoning. A sentence must only have a verb *if you define a sentence as something that must have a verb*. Which is only one of many possible definitions. "That not exactly correct." is a complete, syntactically impeccable sentence in a great many languages. That it is not in English has nothing to do with it not being a sentence, and everything to do with it being in English. Likewise, "No!" is a complete sentence in *all* languages, unless you go to the trouble of explicitly excluding it — and excluding it to what end, precisely? It's just a label that has no effect.

Comment: @RegDwigнt a needle must have a point only if you define a needle as something pointy. Whether the definition is reasonable or not is another matter, using a word according to its definition is hardly circular. Whether something is a sentence or not in another language has no bearing on whether it is one in English where a sentence is [defined](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sentence) by the presence of a verb.

Comment: @terdon I can only repeat that even for English, that is [only one possible definition out of many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_%28linguistics%29). And again, what purpose does it ultimately serve to say that "London." "Implacable November weather." or "No!" are not sentences? You are free to call them unsentences, but that changes nothing at all.

Comment: Replacing 'is' with an equals sign (=) can often help clarify meaning.

Comment: @RegDwigнt no purpose whatsoever as far as I can tell, that was just the definition of _sentence_ I grew up with and was not aware of others. Perhaps the difference is between the jargon used by linguists and that used by high school grammar teachers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The honest answer — *especially* for those who have little to no understanding of esoteric grammar rules, *but also* for those who in fact do — is "there is no reason". It just so happens that English is made that way.

"That not exactly correct" is a perfectly grammatical construction in Russian (or East Slavic languages in general). There, a copula is usually optional, in many cases not an option at all, and in fact for all intents and purposes you could say the word "is" as such *does not even exist*. (I am exaggerating just a little, and a native speaker or a linguist will understand what I mean. For everyone else, some examples follow shortly, so bear with me.)

Now, there is no intrinsic reason for English to be this way and for Russian to be the other. The only reason is "because reasons". Of course that's a disappointing answer to provide, so you actually can try to drive that point home by pointing out that there are also *other* differences, in the very same sentence, to which your tutor apparently is not objecting. So it's a small step for him to also not object to this one and just accept it how it is.

For example, note that in Russian (I will just go ahead and use that one as an example), the word "correct" in the sentence at hand would have to agree in gender and number with the subject ("that"), while English does not even *have* such a thing as inflection of adjectives for gender or number.

- "She is correct, it is correct, we are correct" in Russian would be "she correct[female ending], it correct[neuter ending], we correct[plural ending]".
- "There is a car in the street" would be "On street car".
- "It is cold outside" would be "Outside cold[neuter ending]".
- "Today is my birthday" would be "At mine today birthday".
- "There's something strange about this language" would be "With this language something strange" — where both *language* and *this* would be inflected for case, and for a case not just English, but indeed most languages have never heard of: Instrumentalis.

Note how all these examples must have an "is" in English, and must *not* have an "is" in Russian. From there, it's a tiny step to accept the "that not correct" vs. "that is not correct" discrepancy, as it is indeed the norm and not an exception.

And the reason, again, is pure chance. There is no universal rule that every language must (not) use copulas, or genders, or cases, or aspects, or articles, or the dual number, or a future tense. Some do, others don't. And it took them millennia to develop that way, one tiny step at a time. You can't pin it down to one particular thing.

Comment: It'd be cool if you added some example pairs of analogous sentences which use dash and the word "exist" in place of "is" to show how it can be avoided in certain cases, and yet retain the meaning.

Answer (score 5):

In that sentence *is* is a [copula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28linguistics%29).

It is used in your example to join a subject (*that*) to its description (*not exactly correct*).

Answer (score 5):

I, myself, am a speaker of three Austronesian languages (to which Malaysian belongs), and I can attest to the fact that some Austronesian languages simply don't have the be-verb. For instance, "She's beautiful" in Waray--a Philippine language--would be "Mahusay hiya" (Beautiful she.)

I understand you're not keen on overwhelming your student with a lot of explanation on grammar, and you mustn't. So, as a teacher of English myself, my advice is to use the lexical approach. Teach vocabulary in chunk/ phrases rather than by focusing on individual words. In sentences like 'She's beautiful," students must accept that that small word--the be verb--simply has to be there.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you haven't covered the basic types of verbs in English - the pure copula is one of them. It joins something you're talking about to one of its attributes, for instance, 'the stone is white'.
The verb 'to be' is also used as part of tense formation, eg the present continuous, 'the student is learning'.
It is used as an intransitive verb, where an action is described which starts and ends in the subject, eg 'I think, therefore I am', where the verb denotes existence.
In your sentence, the verb 'to be' is used as a pure copula, with the sense 'That thing is a thing which is not exactly correct'.

Comment: You are, of course, absolutely correct. The problem being, I am a native speaker, not a teacher. While I could certainly try and explain the basic types of verbs in English, I would get it wrong, and I don't want to derail somebody who has a fairly good grasp of English with my poor understanding of the reasoning behind it. Thanks to this question, and this community, I have a better understanding of sentence structure than GCSE English ever taught me. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

I like to illustrate the copula using an equals sign, =.  As in: He = a boy. The copula indicates (more or less) that the thing described on one side of it is equal to, or has characteristics equal to, what is on the other side of it.

I find my students usually accept this and find it makes sense.  A heck of a lot more sense than the "is" in "is going", for example...

Answer (score 1):

I've been teaching English to Spanish speakers. They tend to omit the subject of a sentence, especially the formal subject "it", saying things like "Is difficult for me" or "Is hot today".

In these cases, I try to explain to them that English always needs a subject and a verb, so much so that even in cases where there isn't any logical subject, you must add a non-existent formal one. (*Who* is doing the raining, anyway? And what's *that* that is three o'clock?)

In the original poster's question, the matter was one of omitting the verb "to be". In my experience, for practical purposes of language learning, the answer must be: "In English you must always mention the subject and the verb".

Questions of "why", unfortunately, don't have much place in language learning, since they all fundamentally lead to "because it is so". English basic grammatics requires many things that are not *explicable* other than through intensive linguistical study (which is *not* the same as learning a language), but they are *learnable*. Otherwise, you'll end up trying to explain what the "do" in "Do you like coffee?" means.

Answer (score 0):

Arabic has the same phenomenon for the verb "to be". A method that fairly works is asking him/her to make a broken sentence in their own language, and asking them why it is marked by faulty syntax  -- reflecting thus on one’s own language to enhance linguistic sense for foreign languages.